# Best way to set environment variables for java program?

Tags: java, r, command-line, environment-variables

I am writing a Java program that uses the RJava interface (http://rforge.net/rJava/). Because this allows using R inside of a Java program, I have to make sure the proper environment variables are set when a user tries running this program.

My question is, what is the best way to set these variables? Should I just write a script to set them before the program is executed? The problem with that is, I have to ask the user which directory R is installed in as well as where their R libraries are stored, since the user could really have put this anywhere. I don't think there is any way around that since I need to update the PATH variable with that information for RJava to work correctly and be able to run R and it's libraries within my program.

I get nervous permanently modifying the PATH variable for a user, but I guess other installers for programs do this all the time...

Any suggestions on the best way to make all of this work together well?

Comment: Modifying environment variables only affects the tree of processes rooted at the modifier. You don't affect the shell that launched that process or anything else in the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in "System Properties" when starting java using the -D option.

`java -DLIBRARY_PATH="C:\\SomePath\\" ClassName`

This is probably more suitable for your situation than using environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use one java program to ask the user the R install location, then uses ProcessBuilder to sets up a new process environment (including the R install location, and modifies PATH) and launches a second program which uses the RJava interface.

That way you are not permanently changing the PATH, just for the launched second program.
The launcher program could remember the location to save the user from having to enter it each time.

```
public class Launcher {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String userdir = System.getProperty("user.dir", ".");
    File propertyFile = new File(userdir, "app.properties");

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(propertyFile)) {
      properties.load(in);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // ok
    }

    String location= properties.getProperty("LOCATION", "default");
    System.out.println("Enter Location [" + location+ "]:");

    String string = null;
    try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
      string = in.readLine();
    }

    if ((string != null) && (string.length() > 0)) {
      location = string;
      properties.setProperty("LOCATION", location);
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(propertyFile);
      properties.store(out, "Application properties");
    }

    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.command("java", "-cp", classpath, App.class.getName());
    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("LOCATION", location;
    Process process = pb.start();

    try (
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
      }
    }

    int exitValue = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("exit value = " + exitValue);
  }
}

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("App: Location: " + System.getenv("LOCATION"));
    System.exit(3);
  }
}
```

Comment: Right, so I was thinking about doing something like this, but wouldn't this require the user to input this EVERY time they wanted to run the program? I feel like that would get rather annoying. I mean, I could store the values in a file or something and have an option to change them in the second program, and only run the first if that file isn't there or something? I don't know.